# How to trigger a MWAA dag from python script or from control-m job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, mwaa, control-m

I have an requirement to start the mwaa dag from control-m job or from python script, I guess api call to mwaa from open internet is not allowed.from internet I came to know we can do this by lambda function and S3 event based trigger. Is there any other way to start a dag from control-m?

Please suggest if anyone came across this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the process myself but it is supported in Control-M from version 9.0.20 onwards according to [docs](https://community.bmc.com/s/news/aA33n0000000R7uCAE/airflow-v2-job-type-triggermonitor-a-dag-and-display-tasks-states).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think mwaa is directly  supported by Control M,
but you can trigger jobs from Control M using Apache Airflow UI in mwaa according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/access-airflow-ui.html).